Flickering Black Artifacts in Viewport
I suddenly have these weird black artifacts in my viewport and they won't go away. They flicker whenever I zoom in/out or resize the window. I was wondering if anyone else has ever encountered this issue?

Edit:
I noticed that the artifacts went away when I used the render preview and they only showed up in the material preview when the render pass was either 'combined', 'transparent', or 'volume light'



Render Pass
Artifacts (Material Preview)
Artifacts (Render Preview)




Combined
TRUE
FALSE


Transparent
TRUE
TRUE


Volume Light
TRUE
TRUE


Everything Else
FALSE
FALSE




Both Blender 3.6 and 4.1 have the same issue

That looks like a graphics driver issue. Make sure that you have the latest driver for your machine installed. It might also be worth updating to the latest Blender version. You're using 3.6.2 and 3.6.10 is the latest for that series.

All my drivers are up to date and updating didn't seem to help. Though I noticed that the artifacts went away when I used the rendered preview which is interesting

No idea in that case I'm afraid. Can you try the latest Blender version (4.1.1) assuming that it's compatible with your graphics card?

It still has the black artifacts unfortunately so it must be something wrong with my system. Though I'm confused because I've been using Blender on this system for a few years and it's been fine up until now

Switching to integrated graphics seems to have fixed the issue! I'm just going to use integrated graphics from now on. Tysm for trying to help me fix it!

Switching to integrated graphics has fixed this issue!
